# python list index out of range using pattern library

Tags: python, list

I am calculating sentiment scores which i use pattern library to calculate. I am basically reading from a csv file which has text data only in the first column. somehow i keep getting this error:

```
sentiment_score_list.append(round(sentiment(item[0])[0],1))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is my code:

```
cr = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1],"rU").readlines()[1:])
    text_data=[]
    for row in cr:
        text_data.append(row)
        # print row
         #first col is text

#populate the sentiment score list with just the sentiment score
    sentiment_score_list=[]
    for item in text_data:
        sentiment_score_list.append(round(sentiment(item[0])[0],1))
        print round(sentiment(item[0])[0],1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either `item` or `sentiment(item[0])` is an empty list, for **some** value of `item`.

If the sample code is complete, it's likely `sentiment()` returns an empty list sometimes.

Comment: yeah there was an empty line in the csv file.